# Can't install PyQt5 on Raspberry Pi - tmp file not found error

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, raspberry-pi4

Running RasPi OS on a Pi 4b, 8 gig RAM, 256 gig UHS-1 u-SD card, pip and setuptools upgraded, python 3.7.3.

Warning for Pi users - There is a possible precedence issue during python upgrades, I have needed to use sudo to make sure the distro packages are upgraded. Not using sudo has packages installed under the user's .local/bin - and the /usr libs have precedence.

On to the error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip3 install PyQt5 -U
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting PyQt5
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6e/86/d715e71771cece0e060f2ebab20f3ded067b08a0927dfb3143530cae8098/PyQt5-5.15.3.tar.gz (3.3MB)

    100% |████████████████████████████████| 3.3MB 88kB/s 
  Installing build dependencies ... done

    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tokenize.py", line 447, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')

    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-install-by049ub_/PyQt5/setup.py'
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-by049ub_/PyQt5/

pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

**Doing this without sudo:**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip3 install PyQt5

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple

Collecting PyQt5

  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored

  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored

  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/6c/640e3f5c734c296a7193079a86842a789edb7988dca39eab44579088a1d1/PyQt5-5.15.2.tar.gz

  Installing build dependencies ... done

    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tokenize.py", line 447, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')

    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-install-a8yqsus1/PyQt5/setup.py'

    
    ----------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-a8yqsus1/PyQt5/
```

Going to previous revision does not fix issue. Other packages (such as numpy) have installed or upgraded just fine. PyQt5 install under Windows 10 worked fine.

Has anybody got a fix for this?

Comment: use `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5`